# Normal Binomial distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation, binomial-distribution

Q1. a) Assume that the distribution of birthday during the months of the year is uniform. What is the probability that a class of 120 students, exactly 20 students have their birthdays in either August or September ?
Solving using

i. the exact Binomial distribution

ii. the Normal approximation to the Binomial distribution.

Not sure how to write out my answer but I basically used the formula for the Binomial distribution $\binom nkp^k (1-p)^{n-k}$
Using $p= \frac{120}{365}, \ n=120, \ k=20$.

I have been sitting on a few stats problem since a couple of days and I have tried various ways so if you can help I will appreciate it !

Comment: I don't think that August and September count $120$ days.

Comment: By the way, please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Your binomial formula is correct but $p$ should be $\frac16$.

Your value for $p$ is incorrect, firstly because August and September combine for $62$ days, not $120$, and secondly because the question asks you to treat the months as being distributed uniformly rather than according to their number of days. Since August and September are $2$ of the $12$ months, $p=\frac16$.

The formula for the using the normal approximation is similar to the typical $z$-formula for proportions, and uses the proportion and standard error of the binomial distribution. Since we are using a continuous distribution to approximate a discrete one, we would use an integer correction and look for the probability that $19.5<X<20.5$ You would then find the $p$-value for both $19.5$ and $20.5$ using the $z$-test with the following formula:$$Z={\bar X-\mu\over \sigma}$$ where $\mu=np$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$

Comment: Yes I thought about that too ! Thank You makes more sense and how can I use the normal approximation to the Binomial distribution ?

Comment: @Rahel I added to the answer to include the part about the normal approximation.

Comment: Thank You this is very helpful! I will have a look into that !

Comment: @Rahel No problem, glad to help!  If you like an answer, you can upvote it and/or mark it as an accepted answer.